# How do I get information from a closed window in App.xaml.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have multiple windows. My LoginWindow has to validate the user. If this window is canceled the complete application should shutdown. If the user enter the correct login, the LoginWindow should be closed and the MainWindow open.

[image: Flowchart]

**Question:**
My problem is at the yellow diamond: How to determine the state of the login process?

That is my current state.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var app = new App();
        var login = new LoginWindow();
        if (app.Run(login) == 1) //<-- Problem: How to get the state from login?
        {
            var mainapp = new MainWindow();
            app.Run(mainapp);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to get an exitcode from the loginwindow by using  `Application.Current.Shutdown(1);` but it cause an InvalidOperationException on `app.Run(mainapp);`, because `Shutdown` closes the complete application.

Comment: Environment.Exit(1) ? This will terminate the application.

Comment: Can the user exit the form in any other way than pressing the X button on the ControlBox of the form?

Comment: See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c713c3/how-to-exit-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: @mm8 That shutdown my complete application. The content of the if statement isn't executed anymore.

Comment: @GabrielStancu The user have a "Login" and a "Cancel" Button. I need a "true" "false" return value.

Comment: @PaulF I've read this article. It is not helpfull. There is only one method returning an exit code. But this method close my complete application.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Syrlia, it seems I and others completely misinterpreted your question.  I realise now what you want is to set the return value of Application.Run() in such a way that your application continues and is able to show other windows.  I'll re-edit the title again...

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to set the return code is, as you've said, by calling Application.Current.Shutdown, which will terminate the application.  I could be wrong, so let's throw the question out there.

Comment: Really, though, I don't think your application should be calling Run() multiple times - I think you should be using a different approach to show the login window, like calling ShowDialog() on it, then set a property on LoginWindow object based on the user's action, then examine the property when the login window is closed and ShowDialog() returns.  Is there any reason you can't do something like that?  I know that will work because I've tried it.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, i've found the solution with `ShowDialog`. See my own answer. But can you explain (or give a link) what `App.Run()` does and why i should not call it twice?

Comment: No, not really, it's just a feeling that it's the wrong thing to do :)  See [multiple calls of application run in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923779/multiple-calls-of-application-run-in-wpf) for the results of someone else's investigation for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a smart solution. A Window with return value is called "Dialog".

---

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var app = new App() { ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown };
        if (new LoginWindow().ShowDialog() ?? false == true)
            app.Run(new MainWindow());
    }
```

---

**LoginWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void OnLoginClick(object, EventArgs)
{
    this.DialogResult = true;
}

private void OnCancelClick(object, EventArgs)
{
    this.DialogResult = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Environment.Exit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Environment_Exit_System_Int32_) terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code.

But a window has no "return value". You could handle the `Closed` event for the `LoginWindow` and check whether a property of thw window itself, or its view model, has been set. Please refer to the following example.

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly App app = new App() { ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown };

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow();
        login.Closed += Login_Closed;
        app.Run(login);
    }

    private static void Login_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginWindow loginWindow = (LoginWindow)sender;
        loginWindow.Closed -= Login_Closed;

        if (loginWindow.LoggedIn)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            app.MainWindow = mainWindow;
            app.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
            mainWindow.Show();
        }  
    }
}

public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool LoggedIn { get; private set; }

    private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (authenticate)...
        LoggedIn = true;
        Close();
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoggedIn = false;
        Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To exit the whole application use "Application.exit();" and to open the main windows create object of that form then use "object.Show()" and "this .hide()" to hide the login form.

For example:
Assume the query i.e. stored procedure like:

```
Create procedure dbo.usercheck
(
@userid nvarchar,
@password nvarchar 
)
As
Select username from login table
```

C# code:

```
SqlCommand com=new 
SqlCommand("dbo.usercheck","connection");

If(com.executescalar()==null)
{
Application.exit();
}
else
{
Mainform f=new Mainform();
f.show();
this.hide();
}
```

You can write the "Application.exit();" statement in cancel button's click event to close the application whenever you want to close whole application when clicked on cancel button of login form.

When user enters wrong user id or password then you can show the error message instead exit the application.

Comment: OP doesn't want to exit the whole application

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code:

Declare a bool variable to check if user closed the app or if it was closed from your code:

```
bool userClosedForm = false;
```

Then inside the Close button add this line, after the code you already had there:

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code
        userClosedForm = true;
    }
```

Add a Form_Closed event where you check the value of the variable:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (userClosedForm == true) Application.Exit();
        else 
         {
          //your code to open the next form if the user logged in and you closed the form from code
         }
    }
```

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: As an aside, the `== true` in `if (userClosedForm == true)` is redundant code - `userClosedForm` already evaluates to true or false without the additional check, it's a `bool`.

Comment: Yes, I recently moved from VB.NET, where it doesn't work like that, I'll have to get used to it. It doesn't affect the code though...

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't affect the functionality, it's just redundant code :) I believe it's the same in VB too